# No longer I get SMS notifications

Tags: sms, notifications

I‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌ have installed a few new SMS management apps to test them and uninstalled them because they were not better than the original SMS app. But now I no longer receive any SMS notifications. No alert sounds, no notifications.

How can I turn on notifications again.